# Cmake link issue: undefined reference to QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt4

I just started using Qt. I have a problem with compiling the first example.
main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  QPushButton button ("Hello world !");

 return app.exec();
}
```

CMake.txt:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
 project(new)
 find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
 enable_testing()
 include_directories(${QT_INCLUDES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
 set(source_SRCS main.cpp)
 qt4_automoc(${source_SRCS})
 add_executable(new ${source_SRCS})
 target_link_libraries(new${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY})
 add_subdirectory(tests)
 install(TARGETS new RUNTIME DESTINATION .)
```

The error I get upon building is:

```
undefined reference to `QPushButton::QPushButton(QString const&,QWidget*)'
```

It is a linking problem, but how can I solve it?

Comment: `target_link_libraries(new${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY})` should be `target_link_libraries(new ${QT_LIBRARIES})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three problems:

1. You're not linking with the Gui module (Widgets module in Qt 5). This is covered in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36889305/1329652).
2. You you must use `QApplication` in widgets-based applications. Since `QPushButton` comes from the Gui module (Widgets in Qt5), you can't merely use `QCoreApplication` nor `QGuiApplication`: your program will crash as soon as you attempt to instantiate a `QWidget`.
3. You're not showing the button, so when your program starts you'll see nothing once you fix the above.

Your `main.cpp` should look like:

```
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
#include <QtGui>
#else
#include <QtWidgets>
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QPushButton button ("Hello world !");
  button.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I think you are missing:

```
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED QtGui)
```

looking at your cmake you probably want to change the `target_link_libraries` for the following:

```
target_link_libraries(new ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: This build the program, but the error after execution is "QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget when no GUI is being used
Aborted (core dumped)". But I fail to link against QtWidgets library.

Comment: then the error might be in your main...."Qt requires you to create a QApplication before creating any QWidget subclasses"

Comment: Your last comment helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're also going to need to link against the QtGui and QtWidgets library. Within qmake it handles which of the many libraries make up Qt, you'll have to do this by hand in cmake.

If you look at the documentation for QPushButton (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html), the "qmake" line shows what library you need.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using qmake instead of cmake with Qt.

Anyway, `QCoreApplication` (see [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html)) is the console version of main application class and will not work in GUI application. `QPushButton` is a widget class and can exist alone and will make a window (although you must `show()` it explicitely for that) but only with `QApplication`.

When using qmake in your *.pro file you need to include `widgets` like so:

```
CONFIG += widgets
```

and make sure you don't have

```
CONFIG -= gui
```

If you insist on using cmake then see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't use qmake before, but I will try it. I saw you cmake solution. It fails on this line find_package(Qt4Widgets REQUIRED). Do I need some additional installations. Or to manually add Qt4Widgets .cmake file.

Comment: `find_package(Qt4Widgets REQUIRED)` This is wrong. It should be `find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)`

Answer (score -1):

this answer solves my same problem :)

---

> ok,
>   i had can solve it by myself.
>
> For all they have they problem too:
>
> The error is sourced from the use of "Q_OBJECT".
>   To solve the error, right-cklick on the Project and choose "Run qmake" and after >this: "Rebuild".
>
> Then the error should be disappeared ;-)
>
> -casisto
>
> https://forum.qt.io/topic/52439/get-undefined-reference-error-but-don-t-know-why/2